# Download HTML pages concurrently using the Async CTP

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-ctp, async-await

Attempting to write a HTML crawler using the Async CTP I have gotten stuck as to how to write a recursion free method for accomplishing this.

This is the code I have so far.

```
private readonly ConcurrentStack<LinkItem> _LinkStack;
private readonly Int32 _MaxStackSize;
private readonly WebClient client = new WebClient();

Func<string, string, Task<List<LinkItem>>> DownloadFromLink = async (BaseURL, uri) => 
{
    string html = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(uri);
    return LinkFinder.Find(html, BaseURL);
};

Action<LinkItem> DownloadAndPush = async (o) => 
{
    List<LinkItem> result = await DownloadFromLink(o.BaseURL, o.Href);
    if (this._LinkStack.Count() + result.Count <= this._MaxStackSize)
    {
        this._LinkStack.PushRange(result.ToArray());
        o.Processed = true;
    }  
};

Parallel.ForEach(this._LinkStack, (o) => 
{
    DownloadAndPush(o);
});
```

But obviously this doesn't work as I would hope because at the time that `Parallel.ForEach` executes the first (and only iteration) I only have only 1 item. The simplest approach I can think of to make the `ForEach` recursive but I can't (I don't think) do this as I would quickly run out of stack space.

Could anyone please guide me as to how I can restructure this code, to create what I would describe as a recursive continuation that adds items until either the `MaxStackSize` is reached or the system runs out of memory?

Comment: +1. He who controls the recursion, controls the universe!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the best way to do something like this using C# 5/.Net 4.5 is to use [TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/gg585582). There even is [a walkthrough on how to implement web crawler using it](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bnaya/archive/2012/01/28/tpl-dataflow-walkthrough-part-5.aspx).

Basically, you create one "block" that takes care of downloading one URL and getting the link from it:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

Func<LinkItem, Task<IEnumerable<LinkItem>>> downloadFromLink =
    async link =>
            {
                // WebClient is not guaranteed to be thread-safe,
                // so we shouldn't use one shared instance
                var client = new WebClient();
                string html = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(link.Href);

                return LinkFinder.Find(html, link.BaseURL);
            };

var linkFinderBlock = new TransformManyBlock<LinkItem, LinkItem>(
    downloadFromLink,
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
    { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4, CancellationToken = cts.Token });
```

You can set `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to any value you want. It says at most how many URLs can be downloaded concurrently. If you don't want to limit it at all, you can set it to `DataflowBlockOptions.Unbounded`.

Then you create one block that processes all the downloaded links somehow, like storing them all in a list. It can also decide when to cancel downloading:

```
var links = new List<LinkItem>();

var storeBlock = new ActionBlock<LinkItem>(
    linkItem =>
    {
        links.Add(linkItem);
        if (links.Count == maxSize)
            cts.Cancel();
    });
```

Since we didn't set `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, it defaults to 1. That means using collection that is not thread-safe should be okay here.

We create one more block: it will take a link from `linkFinderBlock`, and pass it both to `storeBlock` and back to `linkFinderBlock`.

```
var broadcastBlock = new BroadcastBlock<LinkItem>(li => li);
```

The lambda in its constructor is a "cloning function". You can use it to create a clone of the item if you want to, but it shouldn't be necessary here, since we don't modify the `LinkItem` after creation.

Now we can connect the blocks together:

```
linkFinderBlock.LinkTo(broadcastBlock);
broadcastBlock.LinkTo(storeBlock);
broadcastBlock.LinkTo(linkFinderBlock);
```

Then we can start processing by giving the first item to `linkFinderBlock` (or `broadcastBlock`, if you want to also send it to `storeBlock`):

```
linkFinderBlock.Post(firstItem);
```

And finally wait until the processing is complete:

```
try
{
    linkFinderBlock.Completion.Wait();
}
catch (AggregateException ex)
{
    if (!(ex.InnerException is TaskCanceledException))
        throw;
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the brilliant explanation. Could you just confirm one thing? If we set MaxDegreeOfParallelism to a number > 1 does this mean I need change the collection type to something like the ConcurrentStack for it to be thread safe?

Comment: Do you mean the  collection in `storeBlock`? And where do you set `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`? If you set `MDOP` of `storeBlock` to > 1, then, yes, you would need to use some thread-safe collection there (or use locks). But if you set `MDOP` of some other block to > 1, it doesn't affect the parallelism of `storeBlock`, so you don't need to consider thread-safety.

Comment: Boy this is going to make me upgrade to 2012! +1